# Rigify hip distortion

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify, vertex-groups

I've set up a rigify rig for a base mesh I've been working with. An issue I've noticed is that the hip bone makes the hips messed up when rotated on the y-axis to the right.

[image]

Here is the file:
[image]

WARNING: The original version of the model had some explicit features. I did my best to edit all of them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your main problem, you need to rotate this bone 180° in *Edit* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>180</kbd>) so that it is aligned with the next spine bones:

[image]

Also you have overlapping vertices in your mesh, so select your character and in *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* with a threshold of 0.001. Now you can parent again *With Automatic Weights*.

Comment: While that fixes some of the issue, I still have a problem where the hip area gets all "swirled up" when rotated or moved in certain directions. I edited the post with what the deformation looks like.

Comment: OK I've edited my answer, it should be good